# LibGDX play sound when hovering button

Tags: java, libgdx, sound, scene2d

I'm trying to make a button that plays a sound when hovering above it with the cursor

So far I created a class which extends the scene2d TextButton and I'm adding a FocusListener. The problem is that the sound is played a lot of times when hovering because this event fires not only once but as long as the button is focused.

```
//When button is hovered
this.addListener(new FocusListener() {

        public boolean handle(Event e) {

            SoundManager.play(hoverSound);

            return true;
        }
});
```

I also tried to make a variable soundPlayed which toggles if the sound is played once but this leads to the sound playing only one time because I don't know how to detect if the button is not focused anymore so i can reset the variable.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You could try using the sound as a music object instead of a sound object as sounds are more for fire and forget effects. Just play the music continuously and turn volume up on hover.

Comment: but if i understand that correctly i still need to detect when the button is not focused any more and thats the thing what leads to the problem.
i know there is a method for the button class called isOver which is true if the button is focused but it seems like a very bad solution for the problem because then i need to check that every time in the gameloop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to play the sound only once during the whole time of the hover.

Since SoundManager does not track sounds it plays, you want to set a flag preventing from playing the sound twice. Then, you should use *enter* and *exit* functions provided by *ClickListener* to reset the flag when you go outside of the actor (your button).

```
public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor)
{
    if (!soundPlayed)
    { 
        SoundManager.play(hoverSound)
        soundPlayed = true;
    }
}

public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor)
{
    soundPlayed = false;
}
```

This way, sound will be played only once during hover, and can be replayed if mouse isn't hover anymore